# MDF file full - cannot find the source of its giant size

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

All,

I am completely at a loss here and I'm hoping you guys can help me out on this one. I am experiencing the following situation on an SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

MDF-file:
Allocated space: 87392.69 MB
Available space: 256.13 MB

The LDF file is only a few megabytes, most of which are available. So as you can see my database is pretty full at the moment. I tried looking for the source of this, but here is where things get "weird".

When check the top tables by usage the top table was only 3 GB big, followed by a few of 1 GB. I've summarized all those totals and came to something around +- 20 GB of data. There's a giant gap here... and I'm not sure where it's coming from. I've been googling for the last few hours hoping to get some pointers, I've checked if any BLOB data was causing this but that seems to be not the case as far as I can see.

Am I missing something here? Did anyone experience something like this before? I can't find anything related to this so I'm completely at your mercy.

If you need any specific details I'll add them when requested.

Top 10 tables based on Aaron's query. (masked names for security reasons)

[image: Top 10 Tables]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us the query you used to check top tables, I guess you are making mistake

Comment: I've used several different ones, and tried the standard reports included. One which I tried was exec sp_spaceused to check for the size. 

Also tried this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094436/how-to-find-largest-objects-in-a-sql-server-database

Comment: You might try running `DBCC UPDATEUSAGE` for the database and then rerun the disk space report. Just to make sure.

Comment: @ShawnMelton Did that, same results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identify the top 10 biggest tables/indexes with this as a starter:

```
SELECT TOP (10) s.name, o.name, ps.row_count,
  used_bytes = ps.used_page_count * 8192,
  reserved_bytes = ps.reserved_page_count * 8192 
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats AS ps 
INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o
ON ps.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
WHERE o.is_ms_shipped = 0
ORDER BY reserved_page_count DESC;
```

SQL Server doesn't just occupy 87 GB for nothing - the space is being used somewhere. Maybe it's in a system table:

```
SELECT TOP (10) s.name, o.name, ps.row_count,
  used_bytes = ps.used_page_count * 8192,
  reserved_bytes = ps.reserved_page_count * 8192 
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats AS ps 
INNER JOIN sys.all_objects AS o -- change this to all_objects
ON ps.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
-- WHERE o.is_ms_shipped = 0 -- comment this out
ORDER BY reserved_page_count DESC;
```

Would also be curious to see what size the backup is, and what happens if you try shrink the data file.

Comment: Well, you cracked this one. It shows sys.sysxmitqueue, sys.sysdercv & sys.sysdesend taking all the space I was missing. Sysxmitqueue is taking a whopping 57 GB alone. 

What can I do with those? Never heard of those tables before.

Comment: It has something to do with broker's it seems (after some googling). I've checked and currently the broker is enabled on tempdb & msdb. It's not active on any of the user databases though. Where can I go from here?

Comment: @J.Vermeire Assuming the database is `msdb` (you might have mentioned that in the question from the start!) then [from here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e89ed1c8-14a3-4ebf-9516-e90687d15dda/how-to-purge-sysxmitqueue-table-in-msdb-sql-server-2005?forum=sqlservicebroker): `ALTER DATABASE [msdb] SET NEW_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;`

Comment: Well no. It's actually a user database, not a system database. Can I run that query on any other database as well, without further consequences?

Comment: As long as you're not actually using Service Broker there, sure. Anyway I assumed it was `msdb` because you said that broker was only enabled in tempdb and msdb. So it must have been enabled in this other database at some point... so if you use `NEW_BROKER` there you may have some other cleanup to do or you may just end up in the same boat.

Comment: Well, I'm not very up to date about these brokers. We might have used them in the past but I'm sure we're not using them now. I've checked and I did find several Broker queues on that database. Can I disable those queues? How do I clean up Service brokers?

Comment: Did some comparing with some other databases and this Database has a lot more broker queues and services going on. Can I delete those (while those queues are still full, most likely)? Since there's no broker enabled on this database, I don't see a reason for them being there...

Comment: Sorry if I'm not making sense but I've checked those queues out some more. Pretty much all of them are empty. Could they be responsible for that bloating, even when they are empty?

Comment: Sure, the queues are empty, but clearly the system tables that support them are not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20702/discussion-between-j-vermeire-and-aaron-bertrand).

Comment: The cleanest thing to do would be to create a new database, copy the tables/procedures etc., then drop the old database.

Comment: In this case that is certainly no option. The database is being used on a almost 24/7 live operation. I'd just like to know what's the best way to clean those brokers. Thanks for all your help so far, It's very appreciated.

Comment: Nothing is 24/7. How do you apply service packs? How do you update your software? The schema? etc. etc. Live with the space until you have a maintenance period. Or if the space is more important, then treat it as such. Spend the time and build a proper migration where new incoming data gets copied to the new database and then flipping it on is just a metadata switch (drop old database, rename new). You might have a 1-second blip there. I'm sure your business will survive.